# How to Schedule Automated EBS Snapshots Using CloudWatch Events using CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ebs

I am trying to recreate the procedure specified in ["Tutorial: Schedule Automated EBS Snapshots Using CloudWatch Events"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/TakeScheduledSnapshot.html) using AWS CLI. I'm almost done, except for one step: setting AWS Permissions (Step 9).

[Setting AWS Permissions using AWS console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSaSD.png)

If I do all the other steps using AWS CLI and Step 9 using AWS console, everything works fine - snapshots are being created periodically. I was even able to create a role that is identical to the one created manually in Step 9 (using "aws iam create-role" and "aws iam put-role-policy") but failed to apply it to my rule.

Is there a way to set AWS Permissions to a CloudWatch rule using AWS CLI?

EDIT: Let me be more specific on that. I do the following:

```
$ aws iam create-role --region <my_region> \
  --role-name "MyRoleForThisRule" \
  --assume-role-policy-document file://<my_role_policy_document>.json
$ aws iam put-role-policy --role-name "MyRoleForThisRule" --policy-name "MyRolePolicyForThisRule" --policy-document file://<my_policy_document>.json
$ aws events put-rule --region <my_region> --name "Snapshot_EBS_Rule" \
  --schedule-expression "cron(0 0 * * ? *)" \
  --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<my_aws_account_id>:role/MyRoleForThisRule
$ aws events put-targets --region <my_region> \
  --rule "Snapshot_EBS_Rule" \
  --targets '{"Input": "\"arn:aws:ec2:<my_region>:<my_aws_account_id>:volume/<my_ebs_volume_id>\"", "Id": "Snapshot_EBS_Target", "Arn": "arn:aws:automation:<my_region>:<my_aws_account_id>:action/EBSCreateSnapshot/EBSCreateSnapshot_MyData"}'
```

As a result:

- a CloudWatch rule is created and scheduled with a proper target and role,
- AWS permissions are **NOT** specified, as shown in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSaSD.png)
- snapshots are **NOT** created unless I set the AWS permissions manually via AWS console.

How can I set AWS permissions using AWS CLI?

Comment: Ok, I overlooked the message from [the tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/TakeScheduledSnapshot.html) stating: **"Creating rules with built-in targets is supported only in the AWS Management Console."** So the answer to my question is: **I cannot** :(

Answer (score 2):

AWS CLI has a [events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/events/index.html#cli-aws-events) parameter to manage cloudwatch events.

You would need to put your new rule associated with the role you've created

```
aws events put-rule --name "EBSSnapshotTaken" \
    --event-pattern "{\"source\":[\"aws.ec2\"],\"detail-type\":[\"EBS Snapshot Notification\"],\"detail\":{\"event\":\"createSnapshot\", \"result\":\"succeeded\",\"source\":\"<arn path of the volume id being backup\""}}" \
    --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyRoleForThisRule"
```

You can also check the [Cloudwatch event types documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#ebs-event-types) for further information about event definition

Comment: I'm already setting --role-arn, but it does not help: AWS permissions are not set and snapshots are not created. See the EDIT section above.